# Installing Ubuntu on a second internal drive in an "independent way" (no boot option)

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, 16.04, grub-efi

I have a 120 Gb SSD drive (`/dev/sda`) where Win7 is installed and a second internal drive (`/dev/sdb`) that I use for data storage. Both of them have GPT partition tables.

Now, I want to install Ubuntu on the secondary drive and so I partitioned it in this way: EFI (fat32), root (ext4), home (ext4) and Data (NTFS).

I want the installation to be fully separate from Windows: at startup, Windows must load automatically without selecting it by grub menu, instead if I want to use Ubuntu I should simply select it in the bios boot override section.

I made an attempt and I selected `/dev/sdb` as boot loader destination, but at the end of the installation I strangely found it in the EFI partion of `/dev/sda` drive instead!

That's not what I want of course. For example, if I decide to format the primary drive for some reason, then I must be able to continue to use Ubuntu on the other drive with no problems and vice versa!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to remove your harddrives to do this:

- Remove the second harddrive
- Install a bootloader to `/dev/sda`
- Insert the second harddrive and remove the SSD
- Install Ubuntu on the second harddrive. Install the bootloader to `/dev/sdb`
- Insert the SSD again

works with USB pendirves, too.

**Tested with** Ubuntu 15.04, 14.04, Arch and OpenSuse

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer man!  
On /dev/sda the bootloader already exists, in fact I created a GPT partition table with Gparted, then I initialized the drive during Win7 installation and the EFI partition containing Windows Boot Manager was automatically created. 
During Ubuntu installation, In order to install the bootloader to /dev/sdb, should I select the EFI partition I manually created when I partitioned the drive?

Comment: as you will have to install the bootloader into an EFI partition you should the partition you created.